# Cassandra CQL support for CONTAINS negation

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

Cassandra supports `CONTAINS` on collections:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName text,
    lastName text,
    phones map<text, text>,
    emails set<text>
);
CREATE INDEX ON contacts (firstName);
CREATE INDEX ON contacts (keys(phones)); // Using the keys function to index the map keys
CREATE INDEX ON contacts (emails);
```

And it is possible to query the `emails` set and check for specific Email. Simply:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE emails CONTAINS 'Benjamin@oops.com';
```

What would be the solution if one wants to check for lack of an element, something like: `DOES NOT CONTAIN`? I couldn't find such functionality in CQL docs, is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 5):

No Cassandra does not support such feature. I can guess you have gone through below article:
[A deep look at the CQL WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247092/order-by-and-like-in-same-cassandra-query)

You have to get the whole collections and filter it from your application.

> > Cassandra also doesn't support the "**is not null**" operator nor the "**not equals**" operator.

These restrictions are because of how C* stores data and how it finds row and scans columns fast. C* stores data in a key-value pair (map of map). It can fast get data by indexing the keys. C* can find the particular item very fast by jumping to the location where the data resides. If you index collections:

> > Sets and lists can index all values found by indexing the collection column. Maps can index a map key, map value, or map entry.

To support 'not feature', C* has to get all the rows or item in a collection and filter out all the results to give you the result which is not very efficient. So C* does not support this. If you need this, you can handle it in your application knowing all the facts and considerations.

**Note: Using C* index has its own performance impacts. Make sure you know all the considerations and use cases.

> > All the cautions about using secondary indexes apply to indexing collections.

[Indexing a collection](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useIndexColl.html)
[When to use an index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html)
[Cassandra CQL mapping](https://www.slideshare.net/DataStax/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure) -> How C* stores collections.